# Issues with inserting an attribute into javascript inside XSLT sheet

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to insert a jquery datatables into an XSLT sheet after a table and am having a problem with getting it to replace @id with the id of the table like it is in other portions of the script.  I suppose it has something to do with escaping, but I tried putting double curly brackets inside the script to no avail.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

The portion of my XSLT looks like:

```
</table>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" >
    <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('{@id}').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sDom": '<"vctable"<"#title"lf>rt<"#bottom"ip><"clear">>',
        "iDisplayLength": 25
        });
        $('{@id}').show();

    });
    ]]>
</xsl:text>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [],
    "sDom": '<"vctable"<"#title"lf>rt<"#bottom"ip><"clear">>',
    "iDisplayLength": 25
    });
    $('#]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[').show();

});]]></xsl:text>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  That seems quite repetitive but at least it is working.  I edited your post to change the $ to an @ for the attribute and add the # for the id.

Comment: I will accept it shortly.  I was looking for alternative methods as well.  Is there any way to avoid using multiple xsl:text entries?

Comment: @Devon, nope. It is the only way as far as I know.